# What is wrong with this Fourier transform? (in python)

Tags: python, numpy, fft, pyfftw

As people who have read my previous posts on this site could tell, I have been trying to implement a PDE solver that uses FFT in Python. The programming part is mostly worked out, but the program produces an (very suitable for this site) overflow error (basically it grows very much until it becomes a `NaN`).

After ruling out all other possibilities, I pinned down the problem to the FFT and the way I am trying to do the derivatives, so I decided to test two different FFT's (`numpy`'s `fft` module and the `pyFFTW` package) with the following code:

```
import pyfftw
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def fftw_(y: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    a = pyfftw.empty_aligned((N, N), dtype=np.float64)
    b = pyfftw.empty_aligned((N, N//2+1), dtype=np.complex128)
    fft_object = pyfftw.FFTW(a, b, axes=(0, 1), direction='FFTW_FORWARD', flags=('FFTW_MEASURE',), threads=12)
    y_hat = fft_object(y)
    return y_hat


def ifftw_(y_hat: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    a = pyfftw.empty_aligned((N, N//2+1), dtype=np.complex128)
    b = pyfftw.empty_aligned((N, N), dtype=np.float64)
    fft_object = pyfftw.FFTW(a, b, axes=(0, 1), direction='FFTW_BACKWARD', flags=('FFTW_MEASURE',), threads=12)
    y = fft_object(y_hat)
    return y


def func(x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    return np.exp(x)*np.sin(y)

dx = 0.02

x = np.arange(-1, 1, dx)
y = np.arange(-1, 1, dx)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

N = len(x)

kxw, kyw = np.meshgrid(np.fft.rfftfreq(N, dx), np.fft.fftfreq(N, dx))
Lapw = -4*np.pi**2*(kxw**2+kyw**2)

kxnp, kynp = np.meshgrid(np.fft.fftfreq(N, dx), np.fft.fftfreq(N, dx))
Lapnp = -4*np.pi**2*(kxnp**2+kynp**2)



z = func(X, Y)

lap_z_w = ifftw_(Lapw*fftw_(z))
lap_z_np = np.fft.ifft2(Lapnp*np.fft.fft2(z))

lap_z_np_mag = np.abs(lap_z_np)
lap_z_np_ang = np.angle(lap_z_np)

plt.imshow(z, cmap='plasma')
plt.colorbar()
plt.savefig("f.png", dpi=200)
plt.clf()

plt.imshow(lap_z_w, cmap='plasma')
plt.colorbar()
plt.savefig("Lap_fftw.png", dpi=200)
plt.clf()

plt.imshow(lap_z_np_mag, cmap='plasma')
plt.colorbar()
plt.savefig("Lap_np_mag.png", dpi=200)
plt.clf()

plt.imshow(lap_z_np_ang, cmap='plasma')
plt.colorbar()
plt.savefig("Lap_np_ang.png", dpi=200)
plt.clf()
```

Here the `np.ndarray`'s named `Lapw` and `Lapnp` are what **I thought** should do the discrete Laplacian. And the function I chose, *eˣsin(y)*, is a harmonic function, so its Laplacian **should** be zero.

But the results from the program are very far from this expected value. In Particular I get:

**The original function f**
[image: The original funciton]

**The "Laplacian" of f with pyFFTW**
[image: The "Laplacian" of f with pyFFTW]

**The magnitude and phase of the "Laplacian" of f with Numpy**
[image: The magnitude]
[image: The phase]

Looking at the values of these plots (please do note the range in the colorbar and the fact that 20000 is not any kind of decent approximation to 0) makes it clear why the program I made is giving an overflow, but I don't know how to correct this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The plots seem fine to me. You expect a zero Laplacian. You get a zero Laplacian. The angle is given by floating-point rounding errors (the angle of the complex value <something close to zero> + i*<something close to zero> is arbitrary of course). You also have some edge effects, which is expected in the DFT. You need to realize that your numerical computations produce an approximation to the result you are hoping to get.

Comment: It is not zero. The colorbar on the side is automatically generated and as you can see it goes up to 20000-25000 depending on which transform is taken. That is not correct.

Comment: If the error was 1/100 or even 1/10 I would say it is a fine approximation. Even the first partial derivatives of the function should be bounded to about 2-4, going to 20000 means there has to be a mistake

Comment: Those are edge effects. Take many copies of your input data, pretend they are tiles, and put the tiles next to each other. You'll see a very sharp transition in between two tiles. The DFT-based filtering reacts to this transition. Either (1) ignore the output near the edges of the domain, or (2) apply a windowing function to your input data and then also ignore the output near the edges of the domain. You cannot expect meaningful results near the edges, there is no data there to compute derivatives.

Comment: But looking at the graph you can see that the defect propagates into the rest of the data as well, not only on the outermost layer but it has a large magnitude inside as well (since it looks colored up to 4 pixels further inside)

Comment: Yes, if you filter through the Fourier Domain your filter has infinite support by definition. All of your output is affected by the edge effect. It’s only the few samples close to the edge where it’s obvious. If you scale your data differently you might notice many more samples affected. If the effect is too strong, use a windowing function. Or use a finite difference approximation to the derivative instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake here is that your assumptions about your function are not correct. e^x sin(y) might seem harmonic, but you only calculated it for -1 < x,y < 1. The `fft` will implicitly continue it periodically, i.e. you get discontinuities at all the edges of your function. If the function is not continuous, it's not harmonic and especially you get divergences in the Fourier transfom. This is what makes your FFT diverge at the edges. Besides that, "far away" from the edges, the results look as expected.